# splitting variable map list (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My variable is defined like below

```
variable "iam_assume_principal_list" {
  description = "IAM principal ARN that can assume the role"
  type        = "map"
  default   = {
    test = <<IAM_ARN_TEST
    "arn:aws:iam::0211111111:user/j2nh~123",
    "arn:aws:iam::3512241111:user/ikmz~"
IAM_ARN_TEST

    prod = <<IAM_ARN_PROD
    "arn:aws:iam::02115555:user/j2nh~123",
    "arn:aws:iam::35122555:user/ikmz~7655"
IAM_ARN_PROD
  }
}
```

Now I need to split the string on ~

arn:aws:iam::0211111111:user/j2nh~123 becomes  "arn:aws:iam::0211111111:user/j2nh" & "123"
arn:aws:iam::3512241111:user/ikmz~ becomes "arn:aws:iam::3512241111:user/ikmz" & null

Below is my code

```
data "template_file" "iam-assume-arn-stmt" {
    template = <<IAM_ASSUM_STMT
    {
      "Sid": "Assume",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          $${iam_assume_principal_list}
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": [
            $${iam_assume_external_list}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
IAM_ASSUM_STMT

     vars {
       iam_assume_principal_list = "${element(split("~",lookup(var.iam_assume_principal_list[count.index],var.environment)),0)}"
       iam_assume_external_list = "${element(split("~",lookup(var.iam_assume_principal_list[count.index],var.environment)),1)}"
     }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Error: data.template_file.iam-assume-arn-stmt: 1 error(s) occurred:

* data.template_file.iam-assume-arn-stmt: At column 21, line 1: lookup: argument 1 should be type map, got type string in:

${element(split("~",lookup(var.iam_assume_principal_list[count.index],var.environment)),0)}
```

here is a simple scenario:

```
variable "ip_cidr" {
  default     = "1.1.1.1/32,2.2.2.2/32,3.3.3.3/32"
}
```

I want below

```
ip_1 = 1.1.1.1
ip_cidr_1 = 32
ip_2 = 2.2.2.2
ip_cidr_2 = 32
ip_3 = 3.3.3.3
ip_cidr_3 = 32
```